# Apache kafka not rebalancing load

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, mapreduce, spark-streaming

Apache kafka is not rebalancing load across multiple instances of the same application under same consumer group running in different spark clusters. We have two spark EMR clusters and one kafka cluster. We deployed the same app (reading from topic 1, writing to topic 2) to both the clusters. There are around 60-70 partitions in topic 1. We expected that the load will get redistributed among both the app instances. However apparently that is not happening. We are seeing identical execution under "streaming" tab in the application master for both the applications.Can someone help in this regard?

Comment: Check how many partitions does the `topic1` have, if there is only one partition, the other consumer will be idle.

Comment: Did you check kafka logs of your app instances to see if there is a rebalance triggered? You can also *try* increasing `session.timeout.ms` (consumer config) to more than 10s (for ex, 3 min), in case if your consumer is not able to prove its liveness to the broker.